# pyodbc - How to perform a select statement using a variable for a parameter

Tags: python, sql, variables, select, pyodbc

I'm trying to iterate through all the rows in a table named Throughput, but for a specific DeviceName (which I have stored in data['DeviceName']. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Throughput WHERE DeviceName=%s"), %(data['DeviceName']):
```

EDIT: also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Throughput WHERE(DeviceName), values(?)", (data['DeviceName']) ):
```

EDIT2: A snippet of my final working code:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Throughput WHERE DeviceName = '%s'" % data['Device Name']
      try:
          for row in cursor.execute(query):
```

Answer (score 58):

You are also able to [parameterize](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters) statements:

```
...
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Throughput WHERE DeviceName = ?", data['DeviceName'])
...
```

This a better approach for the following reasons:

- Protection against SQL injection (you should always validate user input regardless of whether parameterized or dynamic SQL is used)
- You don't have to worry about escaping where clause values with single quotes since parameters are passed to the database separately
- SQL is prepared once, subsequent executions of the query use the prepared statement instead of recompiling

Comment: When doing this, is there any way to print out the whole query, because I am having a date/time conversion error, but I don't know where, however, when I print out the query string, it shows the question marks rather than the actual values that are supposed to replace those question marks. If you could take a look at my problem on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861319/pyodbc-cursor-execute-wont-insert-parameters-into-sql-string?noredirect=1#comment63185389_37861319 I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @M.Barbieri, enable logging in MySQL to see what statement was actually executed.

Comment: "_always validate user input_" seems much too strong regarding parameterized queries. If my parameter requires an integer, and the authorized methods to invoked the code only permit integers, I don't see the benefit. I want all improper methods to fail badly!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if my problem is similar to yours or not but my problem was because I had written a query like
`WHERE date > ?" "OR date NOT LIKE '9%'`
and I'd forgotten to put a simple space (' ') either at the end of the 1st line or the end of the 2nd one. Finally I resolved it just with doing this. And the final code looks like:

```
WHERE date > ? "
            "OR date NOT LIKE '9%'
```

note: pay attention to the final ' ' at the end of the 1st line.