# PyODBC + Pandas + Parameterization

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I'm using PyODBC to connect to Oracle with a connection called cnxn.

I have a list of unique identifiers:
*list1 = [1234, 2345, 3456, 4567]*

I also have a query:

```
query1 = """
select * from tablename where unique_id = ?
""'
```

What I'd like to do is use this list of identifiers to create a pandas dataframe.

As a test, I did this:

```
testid = "1234" (since Oracle wants a string as that id not an integer)
```

However, when I do this:

```
pd.read_sql(query1, cnxn, params = testid)
```

I get *"the sql contains 1 parameter marker, yet 4 were supplied."*

Eventually, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
for i in list1:
    newdataframe.append(pd.read_sql(query1, cnxn, params = i))
```

and have it spit out a dataframe.

I've read the docs on PyODBC and it looks like it specifies ? as the parameter.
I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518148/pyodbc-how-to-perform-a-select-statement-using-a-variable-for-a-parameter) and it's similar, but I need to be able to feed the results into a Pandas dataframe for further manipulation.

I think if I can get the testid working, I'll be on the right track.

Thanks

Comment: just updated to add the single quotes after the query is parsed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [pandas `read_sql` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html): "`params`: List of parameters to pass to execute method".

The `params` needs to be a list (or tuple), and hence the string is interpreted as a list of 4 single characters. But this can be solved easily:

```
pd.read_sql(query1, cnxn, params=[testid])
```