# PYODBC cursor to update the table in SQL database

Tags: pandas, pyodbc

Below is a small sample of my dataframe

```
    In [121]: df
    Out[121]:
  TXN_KEY SEND_AGENT  PAY_AGENT
0  13273870  ANO080012  API352676
1  13274676  AUK359401  API352676
2  13274871  ACL000105  API352676
3  13275398  AED420319  API352676
4  13278566  ARA030210  API352676
5  13278955  AYM003098  API352676
6  13280334  AJ5020114  API352676
7  13280512  A11171047  API352676
8  13281278  AOG010045  API352676
9  13282118  AMX334165  API352676
```

I am trying to use a cursor in pyodbc to update the table "result" in  sql server database with dataframe values

```
cursor.execute("Update result set Pay_Agent = df['PAY_AGENT'][0] where Send_Agent = df['SEND_AGENT'][0]")
```

I get below error:

```
 ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ''PAY_AGENT''. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

But I am making sure that datatypes are properly matched in my update statement.

```
In [126]: type(df['PAY_AGENT'][0])
Out[126]: str

In [127]: type(df['SEND_AGENT'][0])
Out[127]: str
```

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Use parameters to pass the `df` values to SQL Server, instead of trying to embed them in the update statement. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9521382/366335) for details - it references a select query but the steps are the same for an update.

Comment: @Bryan having a hard time following where exactly in your solution are parameters being used to pass to the df. Can you point out how to do that in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to format your query properly using parameters:

```
cursor.execute("Update result set Pay_Agent = ? where Send_Agent = ?", (df['PAY_AGENT'][0], df['SEND_AGENT'][0]))
```

Using bound parameters in this fashion is important in any language you use to avoid possible SQL injection. Good luck!

Comment: any idea on how to parameterise create :

             cursor.execute("""Create table result ? bigint Primary Key, ? varchar(9), ? varchar(9)""",x[0],x[1],x[2]
)
x = df.columns.tolist()
       ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")