# PyODBC, cursor.execute() won't insert parameters into SQL String

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am using pypyodbc to insert data into a database and when I use the cursor.execute() command I try to put the sql string and the parameters, but I get the following error:

```
     SELECT uid FROM HP_DATA WHERE( hpName = ? AND processID = ? AND ipAddress = ? AND port = ? AND usernameTried = ? AND passwordTried = ? AND fileID = ?);
    INSERT INTO HP_DATA_LOGIN_DETAIL(uid, attackDate, gmtOffset) VALUES(?, CONVERT(DATETIME, ?, 126), ?);
    2016-04-19T05:40:58.000
    ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.')
```

This is my code:

```
    # Inserting the info of the file that is read into HP_DATA_LOG
                    #   This is supposed to allow us to check in the future, what files are read/unread
                    print("Inserting File data into HP_DATA_LOG...")
                    log_file_date_read = datetime.datetime.today()
                    log_file_date_added = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(path)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                    file_size = os.path.getsize(path)
                    #log_sql = "INSERT INTO HP_DATA_LOG(dateRead, dateAdded, fileName, fileSize) VALUES("
                    #log_sql += "'" + str(log_file_date_read) + "', "
                    #log_sql += "'" + str(log_file_date_added) + "', "
                    #log_sql += "'" + path + "', "
                    #log_sql += "" + str(file_size) + ");"
                    log_params = (log_file_date_read, log_file_date_added, file_name, file_size)
                    log_sql = '''INSERT INTO HP_DATA_LOG(dateRead, dateAdded, fileName, fileSize) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);'''
                    print(log_sql)
                    cursor.execute(log_sql, log_params)


                    # Getting the auto-generated fileID from the table
                    print("Getting fileID...")
                    #get_fileID_sql = "SELECT fileID FROM HP_DATA_LOG WHERE "
                    #get_fileID_sql += "(dateRead = '" + str(log_file_date_read) + "'"
                    #get_fileID_sql += " AND dateAdded = '" + str(log_file_date_added) + "'"
                    #get_fileID_sql += " AND fileName = '" + path + "'"
                    #get_fileID_sql += " AND fileSize = '" + str(file_size) + "');"
                    fileID_params = (log_file_date_read, log_file_date_added, file_name, file_size)
                    get_fileID_sql = '''SELECT fileID FROM HP_DATA_LOG WHERE (dateRead = ? AND dateAdded = ? AND fileName = ? AND fileSize = ?);'''
                    print(get_fileID_sql)
                    cursor.execute(get_fileID_sql, fileID_params)
                    fileID = cursor.fetchone()

                    # Logging the attack by Inserting the HoneyPot data into HP_DATA
                    hp_name = re.findall('-\d\d:\d\d\s(.*)\ssshd', line)
                    pid = re.findall('\ssshd-22\[(\d+)\]', line)
                    ip_add = re.findall('\sIP:\s(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s', line)
                    port = re.findall('\s.\d+\sPass(.*)Log\s', line)
                    if port == "2222":
                        port = '2222'
                    else:
                        port = '22'
                    username = re.findall('\sUsername:\s(.*)\sPas', line)
                    password = re.findall('\sPassword:\s(.*)', line)
                    #sql = "INSERT INTO HP_DATA(hpName, processID, ipAddress, port, usernameTried, passwordTried, fileID) VALUES("
                    #sql += "'" + hp_name[0] + "', "
                    #sql += str(int(pid[0])) + ", "
                    #sql += "'" + ip_add[0] + "', "
                    #sql += str(port) + ", "
                    #sql += "'" + username[0] + "', "
                    #sql += "'" + password[0] + "', "
                    #sql += str(list(fileID)[0]) + ");"
                    sql_params = (hp_name[0], pid[0], ip_add[0], port, username[0], password[0], fileID[0])
                    sql = '''INSERT INTO HP_DATA(hpName, processID, ipAddress, port, usernameTried, passwordTried, fileID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);'''
                    print(sql)
                    cursor.execute(sql, sql_params)

                    #
                    #user_sql = r"SELECT uid FROM HP_DATA WHERE("
                    #user_sql += "hpName = '" + hp_name[0] + "' AND "
                    #user_sql += "processID = " + str(int(pid[0])) + " AND "
                    #user_sql += "ipAddress = '" + ip_add[0] + "' AND "
                    #user_sql += "port = " + str(port) + " AND "
                    #user_sql += r"usernameTried = '" + username[0] + "' AND "
                    #user_sql += r"passwordTried = '" + password[0] + "' AND "
                    #user_sql += "fileID = " + str(list(fileID)[0]) + ");"
                    user_sql_params = (hp_name[0], pid[0], ip_add[0], port, username[0], password[0], fileID[0])
                    user_sql = '''SELECT uid FROM HP_DATA WHERE( hpName = ? AND processID = ? AND ipAddress = ? AND port = ? AND usernameTried = ? AND passwordTried = ? AND fileID = ?);'''
                    print(user_sql)
                    cursor.execute(user_sql, user_sql_params)
                    uid = cursor.fetchone()

                    # Inserting date and time information in order to prevent duplicates
                    attack_date = re.findall('(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)T', line)
                    timestamp = re.findall('T(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.*).*-.*sshd', line)
                    attack_datetime = attack_date[0] + "T" + timestamp[0] + ".000"
                    gmt_offset = re.findall('\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.*-(\d\d:\d\d)\s', line)
                    #hp_detail_sql = r"INSERT INTO HP_DATA_LOGIN_DETAIL(uid, attackDate, attackTime, gmtOffset) VALUES("
                    #hp_detail_sql += "" + str(uid[0]) + ", "
                    #hp_detail_sql += "'" + attackDate[0] + "', "
                    #hp_detail_sql += "'" + timestamp[0] + "', "
                    #hp_detail_sql += "'" + gmt_offset[0] + "');"
                    hp_detail_sql_params = (uid[0], attack_datetime[0], gmt_offset[0])
                    hp_detail_sql = '''INSERT INTO HP_DATA_LOGIN_DETAIL(uid, attackDate, gmtOffset) VALUES(?, ?, ?);'''
                    print(hp_detail_sql)
                    print(attack_datetime)
                    cursor.execute(hp_detail_sql, hp_detail_sql_params)
        print("Executed insert statements")
```

Comment: The placeholder format are sometimes '?' sometimes ... to me it seems the pypyodbc should be queried (or source read) which param style it expects, then use that, ...

Comment: Like instead of "%s" just put the "?" @Dilettant

Comment: Yes :-) something pypyodbc as setup / initialized expects.

Comment: That seems to be working, however, the reason I switched from ?/%s to simply concatenating to the SQL String was because the DATE and TIME fields were not converting from "Character String" so now I get this error: "The SQL contains 2 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied"

Comment: Do the formats and contents of the `datetime.datetime.today()`et al. call results match the expectation of the pypyodbc resp. database? Can you print some tresults and fill in verbatim these into an sql live query against the db to see if it works - maybe others spotting something obvious will jump in ...

Comment: I updated the question, I replaced the concatenation with "?" and this is the error that I get

Comment: Not sure, but maybe try `INSERT INTO HP_DATA_LOG('dateRead', ...` if the conversion from string to date fails or it is in the payload (as I suggested in the former comment) to try literals coming out of the python dateteim method calls ...

Comment: Right, I agree, however, the data is dynamic, so I can't just add a "\" to every input, because it's dynamically taken from a text file

Comment: Multi-language stacks are sometimes mind boggling, sorry, what I meant was not what I typed: The `VALUES(?, ...)` might need either changing into `VALUES('?', ...)` or if this is not sufficient, then you may need `VALUES(CAST('?' AS DATE), ...)` or something like this. Sorry again for not being sync'ed brain-hand-wise ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I tried all of those, no luck....

Comment: Only the last statement failing? I guess no, But the last statement shouldn't that be (deriving the convert call syntax from your sample): `INSERT INTO HP_DATA_LOGIN_DETAIL(uid, attackDate, gmtOffset) VALUES(?, CONVERT(DATETIME, '?', 126), ?);` (I do not know at this second, what 126 in that convert function  is for, but as long as it is not 42 ... ?

Comment: What is the data type of the `attackDate` column in SQL Server?

Comment: The attackDate is DATETIME @Bryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert the `attack_datetime` value to a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object *before* passing the value to SQL Server.

For example, passing a datetime formatted *string* fails with the same error message you receive

```
...
# assumes connection and cursor objects initialized
create_date_str = "2016-06-16T01:23:45.67890"
sql = "select name, create_date from sys.databases where create_date = ?"
rows = cursor.execute(sql, create_date_str).fetchall()
```

Raises

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in
>    pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date
>   and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')

While converting the datetime string to a datetime *object* succeeds

```
...
# convert datetime string to object, specifying input format
create_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(create_date_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
rows = cursor.execute(sql, create_date).fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried that, however I am getting the error "'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable", any idea what that's from?

Comment: Likely still using `attack_datetime[0]` for the parameter collection, instead of `attack_datetime`. See this explanation of [subscriptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not).

Comment: I mean, attack_datetime = attack_date[0] + "T" + timestamp[0], however I do not explicitly write "strptime(attack_datetime[0])"

Comment: It worked, I changed a little ".*" on the regex end for the attackDate and the formatting went through. Thanks for all the help!