# The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied | pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to send a data from my code to SQL Server, but i got this error:

```
ProgrammingError: 
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'emotion'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

My Code:

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-T7OFQV6\SQLEXPRESS1;'
                      'Database=VidgaEmotionRecognition;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
 
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO FaceEmotion emotion ?''', index_pred_as_int)
```

index_pred is a value from  previous code snippet.

Structure of FaceEmotion table is like this:

```
Column: emotion - nvarchar(50) - allows nulls
Column: _id - int - key identity
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyodbc the sql contains 0 parameter markers but 1 parameters were supplied' 'hy000'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491381/pyodbc-the-sql-contains-0-parameter-markers-but-1-parameters-were-supplied-hy0)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491776/10456732

Comment: I changed my line to this: cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO FaceEmotion emotion ?''', index_pred_as_int)

Now my error: ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'emotion'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire `.execute()` statement you are currently using. Do not bury important additional information in the comments.

Comment: I updated my code, could you please help me?

Comment: Ignore the Python - your SQL is invalid. `INSERT INTO FaceEmotion (emotion) VALUES ('wink');`