# How to parameterize query with pyodbc connected to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql

I am using Python 3.9.7, pyodbc to connect to Microsoft SQL Server. I want to use string parametrize the select @MonthStartDate and select MonthEndDate variables. I tried looking at [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491381/pyodbc-the-sql-contains-0-parameter-markers-but-1-parameters-were-supplied-hy0) and [PyNative tutorial](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/)

```py
query = """

 

    Use [Data]

 

    drop table #temp

 

    declare @MonthStartDate date

    declare @MonthEndDate datetime

    declare @LastOpenDate datetime

 

    select @MonthStartDate= ?

    select @MonthEndDate= ?

    select @LastOpenDate=DATEADD(dd, 7, @MonthEndDate)

 

    select S.Keys into #temp

    from DataJobs J

    inner join DataSent S on J.Id=S.Id

    where  S.EventDate between @MonthStartDate and @MonthEndDate

    group by S.Key

    having count(distinct S.D)>=20 

 

"""

 

params = ('2015-04-01', '2015-04-30 23:59:59.999')
cursor.execute(query, params)

var =cursor.fecthall()
```

I just get this error
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query.

Comment: `where  ltrim(S.EventDate between @MonthStartDate and @MonthEndDate)` makes no sense. How to do left trim a Boolean expression?

Comment: Also, you don't attempt to return a dataset in that batch (the final statement is a `SELECT...INTO`). The `fecthall()` will also just error; if you were using `fetchall()` then it has no results to display, as none were returned.

Comment: @Shmiel Thank. you I edited the link to the stack overflow post

Comment: @Larnu I don't really understand. Yes. I am putting the results of the query into another dataset. But I was able to print out the results before I attempted parameterization.

Comment: You're putting those results (from an invalid query), into a temporary table; you then do **nothing** with that table, your batch ends and SQL Server disposes the table (and the data you didn't use). Why put the data into a temporary table at all? Why all those variables and not directly parametrise the query? Why use a `USE` when you should be just connecting the right database? And, again, what is that `LTRIM` trying to do? That isn't valid syntax.

Comment: @Larnu there is a second part to the query. I split the query up for debugging purposes. The second part just joins the temp table that I created with other tables in the dataframe.  So the query that I originally displayed should return  rows.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry if I come off direct with my response. I want to thank you for your feedback. This code was handed down to me and I'm just trying to make it better. Your questions are helping me out a lot.  Yes. You are right about the USE. I don't need that.

Comment: @Larnu **Why all those variables and not directly parametrize the query?**  This is what I'm trying to do but I just needed a point in the right direction.  I will do more research on how to do this. I will look more into the documentation.